# How do I achieve UINavigationBar animation while scrolling up in iOS Music App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation

When you go to the native iOS Music application you will notice a very cool effect when viewing an Album.

It seems like the view is a UITableView that has a transparent UINavigationController and when you scroll up, the first row of the view fades away and into a navigation bar with the album title.

What is actually going on here and is there a known framework that does this?

[image: Animation Step #1]
[image: Animation Step #2]
[image: Animation Step #3]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any component for this, so I tried to implement something myself.

Basically, I setup a custom header view in the storyboard and constrain it to the navigation bar, with an outlet to the constraint.

Then in the scrollView delegate, I adjust the constant value of the constraint and the alpha of the header and nav bar title, based on the scrolled amount and the contentOffset of the scrollView.

I put up an example project here:

https://github.com/ale84/CustomTableViewHeaderExample

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things at play here.

If I were to implement this, I would first set an observer in my `UITableViewController` subclass, observing the `UITableView`. More specifically observing the `y` position of the tableview or the currently first exposed `indexPath`. The header view (the album art, sharing, favorite, ect) would then animate in correlation of the `y` position. The alpha of the header view changes here as well. Also changing; how much of the header view is exposed to the user. The headerview is a property of the `UITableviewController`, which can be manipulated as the animation progresses. The rate of change could be deduced by a  `UIGestureRecognizer`s velocity (a tip on that here: [Implement velocity in custom UIGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603161/implement-velocity-in-custom-uigesturerecognizer)).

As for the navigation bar, I would set the album name as the nav bar title (on presentation) but keep it hidden. When the animation is complete (the `y` position is above a certain threshold), set the title of the nav bar to not be hidden.

Comment: Thanks @BenJammin Im pretty much on the same page with what you said, except I was going to use the first table row as the header, but as you mention using the tableview header view is much better. But this is a lot of manual work... Im just surprised no one built a library that does this.

Comment: You won't need an observer on the tableView, the callbacks are there in UIScrollViewDelegate (which UITableViewDelegate inherits from) ;)